# Azure Logging and data extrapolation

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have a couple of azure app functions and they use a common application insight.
I trying to understand how best can I use the logs to give a breakup of the errors created.

Explaining further, the app functions work with Guids [Primary Key]; would it be possible to see a related summary.
Something like if I run a query using the id it would bring back all the transactions related to the id?

Thanks
Rajesh

Comment: You would have to store a correlation Id against the transactions if you want to match recorded data to these logs.

Comment: Thank you Chris. Let me try and understand how to store a correlationid and I will then update this question.

Answer (score 1):

there is a field called `operation_Id`, that is used to correlate telemetry. Of course, if you have your own identifier stored in the custom dimensions you can use that one as well. You can add custom properties using a [telemetry initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer) like [this one](https://github.com/Ibis-Software/AppInsightsDemo/blob/master/src/FunctionApp/TelemetryEnrichment.cs).

To get a summary per operation you can execute a kusto query like

```
search operation_Id: "99df71d6ea98bc4792cd2ea4a6d0195e"
| order by timestamp desc
```

You can access the logs by using the menu item "Logs" in the application insights resource.

The other option is to use the `Transaction search` menu item. From there you can access the end-to-end timeline view as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/transaction-diagnostics)

Details about how the correlation is done can be found in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation).